# Can we have more than one namespace in a library (in c++)

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new at oop an I just discover the namespace , I want to know if we can have more than one namespace in a library

Comment: The long and short answer is yes.

Comment: Did you face any problems trying that, or wasn't your textbook clear about that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple:

```
namespace A {};
namespace B {};
```

And nested:

```
// Pre C++17
namespace A {
    namespace B {};
};

// C++ 17+
namespace A::B {};
```